# Python nested dict from a list of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have this list:

```
[{"id": "11a6343897504c219ddec86491394b84", "smile_conf": 
  "99.91191864013672", "mouthopen_conf": "97.74097442626953", "smile":"False",
  "camid": "p2.jpeg"},{"id": "11a6343897504c219ddec864914444", "smile_conf": 
  "99.913333672", "mouthopen_conf": "97.74097442626953", "smile": "True", 
  "camid": "p2.jpeg"},{"id": "11a634344441394b84", "smile_conf": 
  "99.91191864013672", "mouthopen_conf": "97.74097442626953", "smile": "False",
  "camid": "p2.jpeg"}]
```

I want to create a dict like this:

```
{
    {"id": "11a6343897504c219ddec86491394b84",
         {"smile_conf": "99.91191864013672",
             "mouthopen_conf": "97.74097442626953",
             "smile": "False",
             "camid": "p2.jpeg"}
    }
    {"id": "11a6343897504c219ddec864914444",
        {"smile_conf": "99.91191864013672",
            "mouthopen_conf": "97.74097442626953",
            "smile": "True",
            "camid": "p2.jpeg"}
    }
    {"id": "11a634344441394b84",
        {"smile_conf": "99.91191864013672",
            "mouthopen_conf": "97.74097442626953",
            "smile": "True",
            "camid": "p2.jpeg"}

}
```

I try with:

```
mydict = {}
for i in range(0,len(l1)):
    mydict[i] = {}
    for id,cont in l1[i]:
         mydict[i][id] = cont
```

But it doesn't work, it returns an error on nested for.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think you mean `for id,cont in l1[i].items()`

Comment: note: your output format is not possible, looks like a `set` with `dicts` in it.

Comment: Your "desired output" is not a valid python dictionary, in fact it's invalid syntax.

Comment: As your desired output is not possible, could you show how you intend to access it? That would help us suggest possible alternative structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your expected output is

```
{
  "11a6343897504c219ddec86491394b84": {
    "camid": "p2.jpeg",
    "smile": "False",
    "smile_conf": "99.91191864013672",
    "mouthopen_conf": "97.74097442626953"
  },
  "11a634344441394b84": {
    "camid": "p2.jpeg",
    "smile": "False",
    "smile_conf": "99.91191864013672",
    "mouthopen_conf": "97.74097442626953"
  },
  "11a6343897504c219ddec864914444": {
    "camid": "p2.jpeg",
    "smile": "True",
    "smile_conf": "99.913333672",
    "mouthopen_conf": "97.74097442626953"
  }
}
```

then try below simple one:

```
list = [
  {
    "id": "11a6343897504c219ddec86491394b84",
    "smile_conf": "99.91191864013672",
    "mouthopen_conf": "97.74097442626953",
    "smile": "False",
    "camid": "p2.jpeg"
  },
  {
    "id": "11a6343897504c219ddec864914444",
    "smile_conf": "99.913333672",
    "mouthopen_conf": "97.74097442626953",
    "smile": "True",
    "camid": "p2.jpeg"
  },
  {
    "id": "11a634344441394b84",
    "smile_conf": "99.91191864013672",
    "mouthopen_conf": "97.74097442626953",
    "smile": "False",
    "camid": "p2.jpeg"
  }
]

print list

requiredDict = {}

for eachElement in list:
    id = eachElement["id"]
    requiredDict[id] = {}
    del eachElement["id"]
    requiredDict[id] = eachElement

print requiredDict
```

Comment: This shadows the built-in names list and id.

Answer (score 1):

Dicts are used to store key-value pairs, but you are assigning values to indexes, which is the purpose of lists. You don't need to convert the list to dict.
You can just iterate through the list like this:

```
for item in lst:
    <do something>
```

Or you can index the list with integers:

```
lst[n]
```

But dicts are used to store key-value pairs, like this:

```
dct = {}
dct["hello"] = 42
dct[5] = 786
for i in dct.keys(): # Iterate over the keys
    print(i, dct[i])
```

The dict syntax is written like this:

```
dct = {key: val, key2: val2, ...}
```

You cannot have a dict like this: {0, 1, 2, 3} because dicts store key-value pairs. And this is the syntax of sets which cannot be indexed.

```
s = {1, 2, 3}
s[0] # ERROR
```

Sets are useful for checking whether they contain an element.
Also be aware that sets cannot store unhashable (usually mutable) objects. This also applies to dict keys (but not values). So you cannot have a set of dicts.